# trying to understand some codes which is related to closure in js

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function buildList(list) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = 'item' + list[i];
    result.push( function() {console.log(item + ' ' + list[i])} );
  }
  return result;
}

function testList() {
  var fnlist = buildList([1,2,3]);
  fnlist[0]();
}
testList(); 
</script>
```

Question:

IN firefox->console, it shows `item3 undefined`, why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 0):

you can change

> result.push( function() {console.log(item + ' ' + list[i])} );

to

> result.push( function() {console.log(item + ' ' + list[i] + ' ' + i)} );

then you find that i is **3**, you should use clousre to avoid this problem.

Comment: well, you are right, but I have set condition(`i < list.length`) for loop,:`for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)`,if i=3 which is = list.length, should not execute this line: `result.push( function() {console.log(item + ' ' + list[i])} );` so why?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the evaluation of closure reference happens at the execution time of the statement `(item + ' ' + list[i] + ' ' + i`, by that time value of `i` becomes 4, this `list[4]` returns undefined.

The execution sequence will be, you are creating a closure variable `i` in the loop, so all the function references pushed to `result` references the same instance of `i`, any modification done to the variable will be reflected in each of the added function irrespective of when it was added.

The solution in such a case is to create a private closure inside the loop statement using a iife

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8mTCn/)

Comment: there is a solution is that :  var tempI = i;  result.push( function() {console.log(item + ' ' + list[tempI])} );

Comment: @hungdoan, it still will not work as expected because javascript does not have block level scope http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8mTCn/3/

Comment: well, but the end, `i=3` not `4`, but how come when `i=3`, can still execute this line: `result.push( function() {console.log(item + ' ' + list[i])} );`? I have set the condition `i < list.length`, `list.length=3`

Comment: @user2507818 sorry, i thought you were passing 4 elements, then also the logic holds because `list[3]` is undefined