# parameter is missing in jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have code for jquery like this

```
HTML : 
<table class="display">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
    <table class="display">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="menu_3"/> menu 3</label></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <table class="display table-hover">
      <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="submenu_3"/> submenu 3</label></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td><label><input type="checkbox" class="submenu_3"/> submenu 3</label></td>
        </tr>
              </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
JQUERY
for(i=1;i<=6;i++){
        $(".menu_"+i).change(function(){
            $(".submenu_"+i).attr("checked", this.checked);
        });
    }
```

i want to check `menu 3`, then all `submenu 3` checked too, 
and somehow it not works, because  `i` parameter is missing..

i dont know what is happen..

help me guys..

Comment: When the `change` event occurs, `i` will always be equal to `6`. You can use an IIFE like Arun to fix this, or you can omit the loop and use jQuery to do that logic for you like Adeneo.

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
for(i=1;i<=6;i++){
    (function(it){
        $(".menu_"+it).change(function(){
            $(".submenu_"+it).prop("checked", this.checked);
        });
    })(i)
}
```

The problem is the usage of closure variable `i`, also ready the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439342/trying-to-understand-some-codes-which-is-related-to-closure-in-js/17439469#17439469)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the starts with selector to select all `.menu_*` elements, and then `slice()` to get the number to select the relevant `.submenu_*` elements etc. No need for a loop :

```
$('[class^="menu_"]').on('change', function(){
    $(".submenu_" + this.className.slice(-1)).prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AQ6Dh/)

Comment: It binds a change event handler to all elements that has a class that starts with `menu_`, like `menu_1` or `menu_30000` etc. Then it gets the last number and adds it to `.submenu_` to select the right elements, and this would only work with elements with one single class and one single trailing number, but that's how your example code is written, so as long as your actual code is the same, there shouldn't be an issue.